# expected value of Consecutive numbers

Tags: probability, expected-value

We choose randomly a subset $\mathit S$ of size 25 from the set $\{ 1,2,...,100\}$  , what is the expected value of number of Consecutive numbers in $\mathit S$?

Consecutive numbers in $\mathit S$: is a pair $\{ i,i+1\}$ where i$\in$$\mathit S$ and i+1$\in$$\mathit S$.

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that both $1$ and $2$ are in your randomly chosen subset?

Comment: it is:$\frac{\binom{98}{23}}{\binom{100}{25}}$ as Parcly mentioned below,that is the probability of any consecutive pairs not only 1 and 2.If we multiply that by number of possible consecutive pairs we will get the expected value we are looking for.@JMoravitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linearity of expectation is the key. There are 99 consecutive pairs, each one having a $\frac{\binom{98}{23}}{\binom{100}{25}}=\frac{25×24}{100×99}$ chance of being selected. Thus the expected number of consecutive pairs is $\frac{25×24×99}{100×99}=6$.